переименовать файлы в Linux согласно заданным именам в txt-файле используя скрипт
В папке /home/user/Downloads/videos/ расположены скачанные файлы, и из-за того что имена файлов именуются как 000.mp4 при их скачивании, система дописывает нумерацию перед расширением файла - 000.556.mp4.
Также имеется исходная нумерация файла полученная из ссылки на файл на сервере, и информация на уже переименованный файл в файловой системе у меня на ПК, хранится в файле /home/user/Downloads/downloads.txt
downloads.txt внутри, здесь представлена информация только о 3 файлах:
Name: 000.557.mp4
Folder: /home/user/Downloads/videos
URI: http://example.com/videos/2004/000.mp4
Message: Resumable

Name: 000.556.mp4
Folder: /home/user/Downloads/videos
URI: http://example.com/videos/1979/000.mp4
Message: Resumable

Name: 000.555.mp4
Folder: /home/user/Downloads/videos
URI: http://example.com/videos/1977/000.mp4
Message: Resumable

где:
исходное название:
URI: http://example.com/videos/2004/000.mp4

переименованное у меня в системе:
Name: 000.557.mp4

Нужно запустить скрипт с командной строки, который прочитает информацию с файла downloads.txt и переименует все файлы в папке ...videos/ в исходную нумерацию (как файлы хранятся на сервере).
000.557.mp4     ===>    2004.mp4
000.556.mp4     ===>    1979.mp4
000.555.mp4     ===>    1977.mp4

то есть нужно использовать нумерацию, из исходной ссылки, которая указана после example.com/videos/ и перед /000.mp4
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть такой скрипт, чтобы он смог обработать файлы из папки проставив соответствующую нумерацию для каждого файла, понимая что информация на каждый файл разделена переходом на новую строку!?

Почему вы хотите решать задачу именно через bash? Предположительно на питоне это можно реализовать быстрее и с меньшим ущербом для психики.

user207200, вы правы, поправил вопрос, предложите свое решение на языке который посчитаете нужным. цель - переименовать файлыпосредством скрипта в системе линукс согласно требованиям. спасибо.

Как-то так: grep -e Name: -e URI: /home/user/Downloads/downloads.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/ /;s/Name://;s!URI:.*videos/!!;s!/.*!!' | while read -r a b; do echo mv $a $b.mp4; done в каталоге с вашими переименуемыми файлами (если есть сомнения, то язык это bash)

Примерно вот так, без обработки всяких исключительных ситуаций.
import re
import pathlib

vdir = pathlib.Path("/home/user/Downloads/videos/")

with open("/home/user/Downloads/downloads.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        for fname in re.findall("Name: (000.\d+.mp4)", l):
            while True:
                url = re.findall("URI: http://example.com/videos/(\d+)/000(.mp4)", next(f))
                if url:
                    break
            try:
                (vdir / fname).rename(vdir / ''.join(*url))
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print(f'{fname} not found')


А теперь сравните с одной строкой в комментарии под вопросом

@avp зачем? ....

код в файле rename.py, chmod 500, запуск ./rename.py, получаю: ./rename.py: line 1: import: command not found ./rename.py: line 2: import: command not found ./rename.py: line 3: $'\r': command not found ./rename.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token (' '/rename.py: line 4: vdir = pathlib.Path("/home/user/Downloads/videos/"), установлен: python --version - Python 3.9.19
В чем моя ошибка?

@Plush Запуск осуществляется следующим образом: python rename.py

Ваш скрипт работает отлично, запустился сразу и я понимаю как редактировать искомые строки в нем.
Вы можете гарантировать что он не сломается при обработке 1.000 - 5.000 файлов одновременно и не перекрутит данные (которые берет из txt файла: Name, URI) одного файла с данными другого файла, то есть не поменяет данные местами в процессе обработки?
Дамп данных в txt файле хранится как я представил и данные одного файла от другого разделены переводом строки. Пожалуйста, поправьте ваш ответ если он требует доработки с учетом вышесказанного: нагрузка, работа без подмены. Спасибо.

Если текстовый файл строго имеет тот формат, который вы указали в вопросе, то не имеет значения, будет это 3 файла или 1000. О какой подмене вы говорите, я не понял. Добавил в код обработку исключения при отсутствии файла.

Насчет просьбы доработки кода под какие-то не совсем понятные требования. В ответе предложено возможное решение вашей проблемы, вы можете самостоятельно усовершенствовать его в нужном направлении. SO все же не про выполнение чужой работы, а вопрос-ответ.

под подменой понимается когда скрипт возьмет данные:
Name: 000.557.mp4
URI: http://example.com/videos/1979/000.mp4
а должен взять
Name: 000.557.mp4
URI: http://example.com/videos/2004/000.mp4
это требование изначально изложено в вопросе и оно разумно, чтобы не возникло ошибки при чтении и переименовании файлов, так как это испортит решение в целом: все будет перемешано если он начнет читать разные строки не учитывая перевода строки

и я уточнил у вас, достаточно ли вашего ответа чтобы соответствовать требованиям изложенным в вопросе и если да, то я принимаю ответ, а если нет, то просил добавить исправления, например, если скрипт не сможет обработать большое кол-во файлов за один раз -  я это имел в виду.
а "выполнение чужой работы" это не об этом, этот вопрос пригодится кому-то еще.

В данный момент я не вижу причин, чтобы скрипт неправильно работал на корректных данных и уж тем более при обработке большого количества файлов. В конце концов только у вас есть возможность протестировать скрипт на полном наборе данных.

Проверил скрипт, обработка 1.000 файлов за раз -  сработал безупречно. not found работает по каждому файлу из списка, если файл отсутсвует. Позиции из txt файла обработаны корректно без перестановки, проверил все вручную два раза.

Структурированный файл хорошо парсится awk. Для вашего случая подходит вот такая программа:
/Name:/ { name = $2 } # берет имя файла из второго слова в строке, содержащей 'Name:'
/URI:/ { # обрабатывает строку, содержащую 'URI:'
    # извлекает /1977/ и сохраняет в массив arr
    # arr[0] содержит /1977/, arr[1] - 1977
    match($2, /\/([0-9]+)\//, arr); 
    printf "mv %s %s.mp4;\n", name, arr[1]; 
}

На выходе генерирует скрипт для шелла
mv 000.557.mp4 2004.mp4;
mv 000.556.mp4 1979.mp4;
mv 000.555.mp4 1977.mp4;

Можно вытянуть в одну строку:
gawk -e '/Name:/{name=$2};/URI:/{ match($2,/\/([0-9]+)\//, arr); printf "mv %s %s.mp4;\n",name,arr[1]}' some.txt | /bin/sh -s

UPDATE
скрипт rename.sh
#!/bin/bash

txt_file=$1

if [ -z "$txt_file" ]; then
    echo "$0 TEXT_FILE" > /dev/stderr
    exit 1
fi

function mk_script {
    gawk \
        -e '/Name:/{name=$2};/URI:/{ match($2,/\/([0-9]+)\//, arr); printf "mv -- \"%s\" \"%s.mp4\";\n",name,arr[1]}' \
        $txt_file
}

mk_script $1 | sh -s

Этот скрипт вызывается так rename.sh <text-file>
Небольшое изменение в AWK: теперь имена файлов при переименовании оборачиваются в кавычки и после mv добавлена опция --, которая означает, что после этого места знак - не будет интепретироваться как опции.

поместил код в файл rename.sh выставил chmod 500, зпускаю ./rename.sh, при запуске получаю : invalid option
с перечнем "GNU long options:" в чем моя ошибка?

Уберите /bin/sh из скрипта и покажите, что выдаёт awk. Возможно, есть какие-то особенные имена, которые неправильно извлекаются из текстового файла

если убрать "-s" получаю ": No such file or directory", когда "| /bin/sh -s" получаю " ' for reading: No such file or directory"

@Plush я добавил свой скрипт rename.sh, попробуйте его.

поместил скрипт в директорию с видео и туда же txt файл
вызываю $ rename.sh <downloads.txt>
получаю: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

я не силен в этом, возможно что-то не верно запускаю, я принял ответ на python - ответ был дан быстрее
но хочу также добавить вам рейтинг за ваш ответ поэтому исправьте меня, уверен решение на Bash кому-то пригодится
